# Sending SMS to mobile using secure gateway from VB.net 2008 c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, sms

I am developing a desktop application in VS2008 with C#. How can I send an SMS using a secure gateway?

Answer (score 3):

[Sending SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sending+sms) is same for every .net application. Its your SMS gateway provider who have to make it secure. Most of the gateway providers provide HTTP gateway. Some give you the option of [SMPP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_peer-to-peer_protocol) as well. Learn about both and choose the best one for you.

Why do you wan to make it secure?

Answer (score 1):

Just get the string from an sms provider gateway and make the simple web request from your program. Remember to replace the text and the mobile no value before making web request.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any common example you can get.

First you have to contact a SMS gateway provider (for example your mobile phone provider) and request that you want to send SMS messages via their gateway. They will provide you with all the tehnical information and most of the time there is even examples for most of the platforms (ASP.NET, PHP, etc).